# Android NDK: Java JVM openjdkjvmti::MethodUtil::GetMethodName Crash

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, crash, java-native-interface

I am using the Android NDK on a Motorola G6, running Android 8.0.

I am using JNI to perform periodic callbacks to my Java code in the following:

```
if ( data_arg  && g_vm && g_obj ) {
     jint res = (*g_vm)->GetEnv(g_vm, (void**)&g_env, JNI_VERSION_1_6);
     if (res != JNI_OK) {
     res = (*g_vm)->AttachCurrentThread(g_vm, &g_env, NULL);
     if (JNI_OK != res) {
        return NULL;
     }
     jclass interfaceClass = (*g_env)->GetObjectClass(g_env,g_obj);
     if (!interfaceClass) {
        return NULL;
     }
     g_mid = (*g_env)->GetMethodID(g_env,interfaceClass, "readCallback", "(I[B)V");
     if (!g_mid){
        return NULL;
     }
     jbyteArray dataByteArray = (*g_env) -> NewByteArray(g_env,data_arg->len);
     (*g_env)->SetByteArrayRegion(g_env, dataByteArray, 0,data_arg->len,(jbyte*)data_arg->data);
     (*g_env)->CallVoidMethod(g_env, g_obj,(jmethodID)g_mid, (jint)data_arg->len, (jbyteArray)dataByteArray);
     (*g_env)->DeleteLocalRef(g_env,dataByteArray);
     (*g_env)->DeleteLocalRef(g_env,res);
     (*g_env)->DeleteLocalRef(g_env,interfaceClass);
}
```

The `g_vm` and `g_obj` variables are initialized when the app starts up with the following:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_abc_register(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
     int returnValueBool = 1;
     (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &g_vm);
     g_obj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,obj);
     g_env = env;
     g_res = JNI_ERR;
     return (jint)returnValueBool;
}
```

The class that calls the above register method is a static instance.

The callbacks occur about about 20 Hz. The callbacks are called from a single thread, which is why the `DetachCurrentThread` method is not called. The app typically runs ok for a few minutes, until it crashes.

The crash produces the following stack trace:

```
* thread #65, name = 'JVMTI Agent thr', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x765630)
* frame #0: 0x92b8d44e libopenjdkjvmti.so`openjdkjvmti::MethodUtil::GetMethodName(_jvmtiEnv*, _jmethodID*, char**, char**, char**) + 410
```

Before the crash occurs, memory and cpu usage are not excessive, nor is the thread count too high. I do not believe there is a memory leak based on the android profiler view
[shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPZbq.png)

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `DeleteLocalRef` on a `jint` (`res`)? That's not a reference. As an aside, it seems to me like you could move `GetObjectClass` and `GetMethodID` to the `register` function. Method IDs are safe to cache and share among threads.

Comment: I originally had the `GetObjectClass` and `GetMethodID` calls in the `register` function, but the same crash still occurred. I had moved them when debugging. I have tested removing the `DeleteLocalRef` call, but the same crash still occurs.

Comment: That `DeleteLocalRef` should definitely be removed. Another source of concern is your global `g_env`. If you write to that variable elsewhere on another thread you'd be in trouble. And `JNIEnv` pointers cannot be shared between threads anyway, so any such pointer should be either a local variable or a function argument. Other than that, your best option is probably to try to reproduce the crash while debugging with GDB or some other debugger. If that can't be done, then maybe try building with LLVM's AddressSanitizer. Or just remove code piece by piece until the crash goes away.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever find a solution? I am also creating byte arrays in a very high frequency, so it might be related to that?

Comment: I did not, though I did get closer to a solution. I followed Michaels suggestion and only instantiated a single `g_env` variable per call. I believe the problem is that I make more than one callback using the same `g_vm` reference. When I removed all but one callback and used only one `g_vm` reference, the code could run without crashing. However, my project requires more than one callback, so this did not work as a solution. All callbacks occur on the same thread, so it doesn't appear to be a race condition or resource sharing issue.